# Transformation of xy plane to polar coordinates. (What would be the bound of polar coordinate?)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, transformation, polar-coordinates

I have a double integral 
$$\int_0^a \int_0^x (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \operatorname d y \operatorname d x$$

So, I am double-integrating $r^2$

What would be the region of the polar coordinate..?

Comment: I corrected the answer from yesterday.  Please let me know if this sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^a \int_0^x (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} dy dx &= \int_{0}^{\pi /4} \int_0^{a/\cos \phi} \rho^2 d\rho d\phi\\
&= \frac{a^3}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi /4} \sec^3(\phi) d\phi
\end{align}$$

which can be evaluated in closed form with some effort.

Comment: shouldn't it be a/cosθ ? and how did you figure out the range of θ?

Comment: I thought that x=rcosθ and we know 0<x<a so 0<rcosθ<a and 0<r<a/cosθ

Comment: @Dr.MV The sector of interest is *below* the line $y=x$, as $y\in[0..x]$ so we require $\phi \in [0..\pi/4]$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks.  Made the adjustment.

Answer (score -1):

Your region of integration goes from $0$ to $a$ in the horizontal direction and from $0$ to $x$ in the vertical direction, so it is an isosceles right triangle bounded by $(0,0),\ (a,0),\ (a,a)$  What is the range of $\theta$ occupied by the triangle?

A picture is below with $a \approx 4.5$.  The range of $\theta$ is $0$ to $\pi/4$  You also need to be able to see that the inner integral (over $r$) ranges from $0$ to $a/\cos \theta$
[image]

Comment: Hi I just don't understand why it is isosceles right triangle, could you explain more about it and how can I determine the range of θ. Since it is on the first quadrant, shoulndn't it be 0 to pi/2?

Comment: I suggest you draw a picture on graph paper.  $x$ ranges from $0$ to $a$, so mark a segment from $(0,0)$ to $(0,a)$.  Then for a given $x$, we have $y$ ranging from $0$ to $x$.  Pick some points along the$x$ axis and color the range of $y$  this represents.

Comment: I mean, this is region of xy plane. What would be new region when transformed into polar coordinate?

Comment: @user226741 $\langle x, y\rangle \in [0; a]\times[0; x]$ is a area within the $[0;a]^2$ square that also lies on and beneath the line $y=x$.  That is the triangle Ross Millikan described.  The area is only within one half of the first quadrant.